# How can I make a generic type optional?

Tags: generics, typescript

I have the following logging method:

```js
private logData<T, S>(operation: string, responseData: T, requestData?: S) {
    this.logger.log(operation + ' ' + this.url);
    if (requestData) {
        this.logger.log('SENT');
        this.logger.log(requestData);
    }
    this.logger.log('RECEIVED');
    this.logger.log(responseData);
    return responseData;
}
```

The `requestData` is optional. I want to be able to call `logData` without having to specify the `S` type when I don't send the `requestData` to the method: instead of: `this.logData<T, any>('GET', data)`, I want to call `this.logData<T>('GET', data)`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe overload the function instead? Or maybe try using a default parameter.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to overload, if I do something like `private logData<T>(operation: string, responseData: T)` and `private logData<T, S>(operation: string, responseData: T, requestData: S)` I will get an duplicate function definition error

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per TypeScript 2.2 (you can try it in the TS Playground), calling `this.logData("GET", data)` (with `data` of type `T`) gets inferred succesfully as `this.logData<T, {}>("GET", data)`.

The overload suggested by David Bohunek can be applied if the inference fails with the TS version you use. Anyway, ensure that the second signature is before declared and then defined, otherwise it would not participate in the available overloads.

```
// Declarations
private logData<T>(operation: string, responseData: T);
private logData<T, S>(operation: string, responseData: T, requestData?: S);
// Definition
private logData<T, S>(operation: string, responseData: T, requestData?: S) {
    // Body
}
```

Comment: On TS 3.8.3, it gets inferred as `unknown` instead of `{}`

Comment: How do I avoid to specify the second type when I want to use the `requestData` parameter? 'Cause when I use this one I need to pass a second type

Answer (score 271):

As of TypeScript 2.3, you can use [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

```
private logData<T, S = {}>(operation: string, responseData: T, requestData?: S) {
  // your implementation here
}
```

Comment: Curious if using `S = never` would enforce the type get specified when the optional parameter is used.

Comment: `S = any` should allow any type

Comment: @cchamberlain Unfortunately, you can not have type definitions with this approach

Comment: Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value". eslint(@typescript-eslint/ban-types)

Comment: @cchamberlain you can do `S extends T = never`, not sure if that was your question

Answer (score 143):

> TS Update 2020:
> Giving `void` will make the generic type optional.

```
type SomeType<T = void> = OtherType<T>;
```

The answer above where a default value as the object is given make it optional but still give value to it.

---

> Example with default type value is `{}`:

```
type BaseFunctionType<T1, T2> = (a:T1, b:T2) => void;

type FunctionType<T = {}> = BaseFunctionType<{name: string}, T>

const someFunction:FunctionType = (a) => {

}

someFunction({ name: "Siraj" });
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
// Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=33#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgMQK4DsDGwCWB7dAFXAgB5CBGAGikICYA+KAXigAo4AuSmgI27oBKFkwBueHABMA3AChZoSFDRZcBYpHIsoAbwC+TVvCQrs+IiVI70cALYROUBMABOOdAHM9NQg3mYCZyc8e1M1dE4w8w1oVg5hZiYdeT15BBCUDDMCNh0oG3tHACIAZRwXOAArIqg9QWkgA)

---

> Example with default generic type value is `void`

```
type BaseFunctionType<T1, T2> = (a:T1, b:T2) => void;

type FunctionType<T = void> = BaseFunctionType<{name: string}, T>

const someFunction:FunctionType = (a) => {

}

someFunction({ name: "Siraj" })
```

This is a good read on making generics optional.

[Optional generic type in Typescript](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/optional-generic-typescript)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#)

Comment: If you want to have the type mandatory, but limit the types the generic can accept, you can also put `<T extends MyInterface1 | MyInterface2 | MyInterface3>` etc.

Comment: Right @amphetamachine . I'm aware. 

Comment: Lovely, thanks. Where is this documented (officially)?

Comment: @amphetamachine Unfortunately, I cannot implement it with type definitions

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking for an optional generic type **within a Type/Interface declaration**, this might help.

(came looking for this, only found answers dealing with generic function declarations. [Siraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62280834/2072165) got me on the right track.)

```js
type ResponseWithMessage = {
  message: string;
};

interface ResponseWithData<T> extends ResponseWithMessage {
  data: T;
}

export type ResponseObject<T = void> = T extends void
  ? ResponseWithMessage
  : ResponseWithData<T>;
```

Answer (score 4):

How about [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)?

> Constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

Answer (score 4):

- `void` doesn't play well where some kind of object is expected. Edit: plays perfectly well, you just have to consider the fact that
  `void` will override anything you merge it with (`void & string` is
  basically `void`) - this is probably the one you want
- `unknown`
- `{}` basically the same as `unknown`

```
interface OffsetPagination {
    offset: number;
    limit: number;
}

interface PagePagination {
    page: number;
    size: number;
}

type HttpListParams<
    PaginationType extends OffsetPagination | PagePagination | void = void,
    Params = {
        filter?: string;
    },
> = PaginationType extends void ? Params : PaginationType & Params;
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIxgZwmACnAc1DjGAHsRkBvAWAChlHkyNswAuZEAVwFsAjaAG56TZABtgvYBy59BUEXQC%209eqEixEKfAQi7ipCtVFMADoQiceA4acaZgALytzbi%20qrr0wATzMoABJgYGYAMsCYeHBQcLyYADz2yAYgJOQgACr%20KBAAHpAgACaYaKw4qenGAD4plpVGlLUAbmTARcgAvMit7QA0yfix8V0mDGJMMMDimgD8nFFQoARKYsoDdAB8ow0Z2QHI%20YUlPW0ds3XDpZy7FPsoAGSXcZhK9AgUUcgWVwAMnMFQhEokMXqMqMo3nQPiAvj8XgBGAEhcKRaJXBLoLAVQiGDLbbq0caMSTSWS-DZiFjY8kbSFqaGfMDfGIvABMyKBaNB8QSun0uLSjQJYzEFj0nApyUcLkldKUQA)

Comment: Hi! Correct will be ```PaginationType = void extends void ? Params : PaginationType & Params;```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the overloading method like this:

```
private logData<T>(operation: string, responseData: T);
private logData<T, S>(operation: string, responseData: T, requestData?: S) {
    this.logger.log(operation + ' ' + this.url);
    if (requestData) {
        this.logger.log('SENT');
        this.logger.log(requestData);
    }
    this.logger.log('RECEIVED');
    this.logger.log(responseData);
    return responseData;
}
```

But I don't think you really need it, because you don't have to write `this.logData<T, any>('GET', data)` instead just write `this.logData('GET', data)`. The `T` type will be infered

Comment: I'd be careful with generic and the conditional statement of this code. If the generic `S` is of type boolean or number it will fail to go inside the `if(requireData)` because the boolean value false and the number value 0 will be false. It would be more resilient to use `if(requestData !== undefined)`.