# new EventEmitter() vs new EventEmitter<Something>()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics

Let's say I have this code:

```
export class ProductsListComponent {
  @Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;

  constructor() { 
    this.onProductSelected = new EventEmitter();
  }
}
```

This is some example of `EventEmitter` usage. I don't understand why first we declare onProductSelect explicitly stating that it is `EventEmitter` that carries Product instance, and then we instantiate it with just `new EventEmitter()`. Why not `new EventEmitter<Product>()`?

I think that in C# I would have to go with the second way, because otherwise it wouldn't compile if `EventEmitter` was generic.
Why doesn't TypeScript require that?

---

//EDIT:

Further clarification fo my question.
What's the difference between:

```
@Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;
this.onProductSelected = new EventEmitter();
```

and

```
@Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter;
this.onProductSelected = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525094/typescript-optional-generic-type

Comment: No, not really. The other question was about how to create an instance of generic class where one of generic types is not really needed in such instance. My question is about difference in instantiation with and without specifying the generic type.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [documentation chapter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics), type argument inference occurs when type isn't specified for generic class or function.

A function can infer `T` type from its argument or return types, and a class can infer `T` type from constructor argument or return types:

```
function foo<T>(v: T) { return v }
foo(1); // T inferred to number

class Foo<T> {
  constructor(v: T) {}
}
new Foo(1); // T inferred to number
```

If there's nothing to infer, `T` is inferred to empty object `{}` [for some reason](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5884#issuecomment-166384984):

```
class Foo<T> {
  foo(v: T) {}
}

new Foo().foo(1); // T inferred to {}
```

In order to avoid inference to `{}`, default type can be provided:

```
class Foo<T = string> {
  foo(v: T) {}
}

new Foo().foo(1); // type error
```

If generic class or function isn't supposed to be used with default type, some impossible type can be specified:

```
class Foo<T = never> {
  foo(v: T) {}
}

new Foo(); // no type error, T isn't involved
new Foo().foo(<any>1); // type error
```

Since `EventEmitter` generic class has no default type specified, the latter is inferred to `{}`. There usually won't be problems with that, because `emit` is [the only method that is affected by generic type](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.3/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L78). Since all non-nully types can be coerced to object type, this usually won't cause type errors - as long as nully types are ignored.

[`strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) will be a problem for `EventEmitter` with default type and nully values:

```
const ee = new EventEmitter();
ee.emit(null); // type error
```

So for all-round `EventEmitter` it shouldn't rely on default type and be instantiated as:

```
const ee = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Answer (score 3):

`EventEmitter()` will work the same as `EventEmitter<any>()`.
If you draw this in HTML on the selector of `ProductsListComponents`,
then you can listen to `onProductSelected` event and assign an action like `onSelected` when that happens. By default you'll get a new `EventEmitter<any>()`, and defining a variable of `any` type is the generic approach in Typescript.

```
<product-list (onProductSelected)="onSelected($event)"> </product-list>
```

So every time in your child you call

```
this.onProductSelected.emit("hello");
this.onProductSelected.emit(1);
```

Parent's function `onSelected($event)` will get called and you can do anything with that data.

---

If you're only expecting one type of data to get outputted to the parent so it can further handle it, then you'd want to stick to a specific data type.

```
onProductSelected: Product = new EventEmitter<Product>(); 
products: Product[];
```

then somewhere in your code you can trigger to emit

```
this.onProductSelected.emit(this.products[1]);
```

---

Added an [example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iswwac?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

Regarding your updated question

`@Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter;` is an error, because here you're declaring a type (after `:`, before `=`), as oppose to defining a type (after `=`), when you declare it as an EventEmitter you do need an argument `<type>`

If you declare the type of EventEmitter, then the compiler will make sure you don't emit anything other than Product type, or what type you declare it to be.

```
@Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand one thing: onProductSelected: Product = new EventEmitter<Product>();  Why onProductSelected has a type Product here and is assigned a new object of type EventEmitter<Product>?

Comment: I added an EDIT to my original question

Comment: It isn't equivalent to EventEmitter<any>().

Comment: @estus it is using Angular's EventEmitter at least. This answer is directed at Angular Framework because of the tag. Updated answer to show it does work

Comment: I'm very aware that this is Angular question. I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm saying that EventEmitter() isn't equivalent to EventEmitter<any>(). It is equivalent to EventEmitter<{}>(), which is a different thing and may have its consequences. See my answer for the explanation.