# TypeScript child class: how to set argument type and return type of method defined in the parent class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a parent class which requires child classes to implement a custom `businesslogic()` method. There is more than one child class, and each child class has a different type signature for its corresponding `businesslogic()` method.

There is a common method in the parent class: its return value depends on the child's `businesslogic()` implementation.

I do hope this piece of code demonstrates that:

```js
abstract class Parent {
  protected name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  protected abstract businesslogic(params?: unknown): unknown;

  public setup(params?: unknown): unknown {
    // business logic involving `params`
    const foo = this.businesslogic(params);
    // do something with the result of the business logic
    console.log(foo);
    // and then return it
    return foo;
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  businesslogic(c: number): number {
    return c + 1;
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  businesslogic(c: string): string {
    return c;
  }
}

const c1 = new Child1("Mirco");
c1.setup(1);

const c2 = new Child2("Isolde");
c2.setup("a");
```

In this example, these two child classes each implement a custom `businesslogic()` -- differing with respect to the type signature.

`tsc` seems to evaluate `c1.setup(1)` against the general signature `Parent.setup(params?: unknown): unknown` -- which works. But I am now looking for a better way where I can somewhat "override" the type signature of `setup(params?: unknown): unknown` within the declaration of the child class to achieve stronger type constraints when calling a child's `setup()` method.

That is, I do believe that the following is what I want: within the child class declaration I'd like to override the type signature of the common method in the parent class. (How) Is that possible?

I also appreciate pointers to more elegant solutions to this kind of problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to design and type these relations, here is a way using generics and Typescript 4 new variadic tuple types. You specify the business logic function parameters and return-type as the generic types passed to the Parent class.

Passing wrong parameter types to `setup` or trying to assign its return value to different type will not compile.

```
abstract class Parent<T extends unknown[], U> {
  protected name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  protected abstract businesslogic(...params: [...T]): U;

  public setup(...params: [...T]): U {
    // business logic involving `params`
    const foo = this.businesslogic(...params);
    // do something with the result of the business logic
    console.log(foo);
    // and then return it
    return foo;
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent<[number], number> {
  businesslogic(c: number): number {
    return c + 1;
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent<[string], string> {
  businesslogic(c: string): string {
    return c;
  }
}

class Child3 extends Parent<[number, string], string> {
  businesslogic(x: number, c: string): string {
    return x + 1 + c;
  }
}

class Child4 extends Parent<[], string> {
  businesslogic(): string {
    return "";
  }
}

const c1 = new Child1("Mirco");
// r1 is a number
const r1 = c1.setup(1);

const c2 = new Child2("Isolde");
// r2 is a string
const r2 = c2.setup("a");

const c3 = new Child3("Another one");
// Child3 expects 2 parameters for setup
// r3 is a string
const r3 = c3.setup(1, "a");

const c4 = new Child4("Yet another");
// Child4 expects no parameters for setup
const r4 = c4.setup();
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking this through @danielv! After all I did not use the variadic tuple types but could get away with something a little simpler -- but this is certainly a lovely generic answer which totally pointed me into the right direction(s)! I also learned that a generic optional type which defaults to `void` can be used to _not_ require a parameter at all, but when a child class overrides it to something other than `void` it becomes a required parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62280834/145400