# A generic game - not providing correct parameter type (unknown)

Tags: typescript

Here is [playground](https://shorturl.at/uxGOY)

I have a generic parameter type of two functions, one that takes two arguments and the other only one:

```
const fn =
  <K, P, R>(inputfn: ((key: K) => R) | ((key: K, params: P) => R))
```

Inside this function there is another one called `get`

```
function get(params: P)
```

that `fn` is returning:

```
const fn =
  <K, P, R>(inputfn: ((key: K) => R) | ((key: K, params: P) => R)) =>
  (api: K) => {

  function get(params: P) {
      return 'get'
    }
    return get
}
```

Here are some use cases:

```
const get1 = fn((key: string, params: string) => ({ [key]: params }))('foo') // giving parameter correct type
const get2 = fn((key: string, params?: string) => ({ [key]: params }))('foo') // giving parameter correct type

const get3 = fn((key: string) => ({ [key]: 'params' }))('foo') // providing unknown as parameter type
```

As you see, the last one is giving me `params: unknown` as type information for the `get3` function

How do you make TS infer this correctly?

**Edit**
By correctly I mean `undefined` basically. I don't want TS to complain that I'm not providing any argument when calling `get3`

Comment: What would you expect the type of `P` to be? In `get3` there is no place for TS to infer `P` from. It's not clear to me either what `P` should be and why.

Comment: what should the correct type be?

Comment: should be `undefined` since i'm not supplying any. so i would like to be able to call `get3` without ts complaining that i'm not supplying any argument

Comment: [Default generic parameter of `undefined`](https://tsplay.dev/w8xLPw)

Comment: ahh thank you! it still complained about 0 arguments but i defaulted it to `never` and now it works!

Comment: Odd since I tried it in the playground and it was fine. Must be TSConfig difference.

Comment: actually, it worked but then it stopped working and now it keeps complaining on the `never` as well.
do you have any idea what ts-config prop could affect this?

Comment: solved it. the answer is to make it `void`

Answer (score 0):

(thanks @caTS)

solved by defaulting generic type to `void`:

```
<K, R,  P = void>(inputfn: (...)
```

more reading here

[Optional generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525094/optional-generic-type)

and

https://garbagevalue.com/blog/optional-generic-typescript