# Optional Generic Parameters in C# method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a C# method with a generic parameter that I would like to make optional. For example:

```cs
public List<TEntity> DynamicQuery<TEntity, T>(T filterObject){
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseCtx()){
         IQueryable<TEntity> query = ctx.Set<TEntity>();
         if(filterObject != null){
             foreach (PropertyInfo prop in filterObject.GetType().GetProperties()){
                 //do dynamic filtering stuff
             }
         }
         return query.ToList();
    }

}
```

I would like to be able to call `DynamicQuery<SomeEntity>(null)` with null. I am aware that I can overload the function and exclude the generic parameter. I am interested in knowing if there is a reasonable way to approach this in C#. An almost identical question has been asked for typescript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43777573/22570649), and typescript actually supports it!

Comment: If you are asking default generic type parameter, C# doesn't have that. But you can use a default valued parameter you can use `default` keyword for the default value of the parameter but yet you need to specify the filter type parameter. So having an overload is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `default` for your parameter, which will work on types that are not nullable:

```
public List<TEntity> DynamicQuery<TEntity, T>(T filterObject = default){
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseCtx())
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = ctx.Set<TEntity>();
        if(filterObject != default)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in filterObject.GetType().GetProperties()){
                //do dynamic filtering stuff
            }
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Nope, OP wants default type argument like in typescript, where you can write something like this : `DynamicQuery<TEntity, T = typeof(object)>`. When you omit the 2. type argument object type will be used.

Comment: Seem to be day of asking "variable generics" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77260805/can-i-have-a-variant-number-of-generic-parameters-for-a-method-call

Comment: This won't work because you still need to specify some type T to call the function